# Is the JPGraph library dead?

Tags: jpgraph

I cannot find any link to the official jpgraph forum. Moreover, the last "real" release was made more than one year ago. Is this library dead? If so, what library could be used in its place with minimal disruption to existing code?

Perhaps there has been a fork that I'm not finding?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to solicit objectivity in the answers that you might receive. Please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more guidelines on how to ask on topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since they've been purchased by asial the development stopped. There is no fork as it's a pure commercial product now. However there are other really professional PHP solutions around. If you don't need PHP, take a look at the google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As per your second question:

While its true that JPGraph is a PHP library, the free and open source JQPlot library for Jquery http://www.jqplot.com is great as a replacement. This Jquery library works similar to JPGraph but with all added features of js/jquery included.  JQPlot has the same "cut and paste then customize" feel of JPGraph.  In fact, I briefly thought JQPlot was the js successor of JPGraph. The main difference is that you'll be working with js/JSON instead of PHP which could be a turn off.